# Using SFTP to set up SSH key login

Tags: linux, ssh, shell, sftp

Actually... a server *that does not have an SSH shell*?

When you login, many hosts say:

```
Shell access is not enabled on your account!
If you need shell access please contact support.
```

But they support SFTP and `id_`rsa login for SFTP.

Is it possible to use the SFTP on the command line to transfer my public key for login?

Comment: This message suggests that public-key is actually in place but the shell in /etc/passwd if set to some jail-shell instead of bash or whatever interactive shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the configuration, but generally, you should be able to replicate what `ssh-copy-id` does in `sftp` batch file:

```
!cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub > /tmp/authorized_keys # prepare filename with keys
mkdir .ssh
put /tmp/authorized_keys .ssh/
!rm /tmp/authorized_keys # cleanup
```

but this has its limitations:

- If there is already some key in `authorized_keys`, it will get overwritten (you can download the existing file locally and append locally
- If the directory already exists, it might fail
- It takes only `id_rsa` (as a proof of concept). Adding other keys is quite straightforward

Storing the above file in `copy-id.sftp` and running `sftp -b copy-id.sftp your_host` should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP_chroot#Fixing_path_for_authorized_keys

You may be forcing sftp only like below match. In that case use the above via

```
# AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/authorized_keys/%u .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile /sftp/%u/.ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys
Subsystem sftp  /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Match Group sftp
        PasswordAuthentication yes
        ChrootDirectory /sftp
        ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /%u
        PermitTunnel no
        AllowAgentForwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        X11Forwarding no
```